# Данные из формы полей Битрикс

Tags: битрикс, битрикс24

Сделал форму которая добавляет отзыв к товару.
Есть несколько полей.
Отправляю их на обработку обработчику.
На стороне обработчика подключаю модуль инфоблока что бы внести данные в таблицу.
CModule::IncludeModule("main"))
Далее выдает ошибку что модуль не найден.
Если подключаю require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/header.php");
то ошибку пропадает и страница загружается, но print_r($_POST) пустой.
Подскажите пожалуйста что не так?
Как правильно получить данные из формы и внести их в таблицу инфоблока?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте в начале страницы обработчика добавить

```
<? require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/bitrix/modules/main/include/prolog_before.php"); ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

`CModule::IncludeModule("iblock")`
Вот это модуль инфоблока. Модуль main я почему-то посредством гугла найти не смог. Но модуль инфоблока определенно iblock.